# What kind of projection to use for D3 and topojson maps of Mexican cities?

Tags: d3.js, topojson

I am converting city block shapefiles of Mexican cities using Topojson and I want to add points with their corresponding latitude and longitude coordinates. I am a bit confused when it comes to the appropriate kind of projection and coordinate system to use.

The answer to this question might be rather simple and straightforward, nonetheless, I still want to ask. If I have "[19.052172, -98.285155]" this kind of coordinates format, what kind of projection should I use based on the options listed in the following links?

https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Geo-Projections#conicConformal

https://github.com/d3/d3-geo-projection/

I am trying to grasp projections once for all, any advices and sources are highly appreciated. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you focus on a single city (<50 * 50 miles), the projection is fairely irrelevant. I would advice you to stick with the mercator or [equirectangular](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3757119) projections. It gives [elegant results](http://bl.ocks.org/hugolpz/560f56d2cd1899b0982f).

Comment: thanks! I've done my studies based on your answer.. thanks again